# How to pass program options in boost without argument name having all other options beeing fully avalible

Tags: c++11, boost-program-options

I was wondering how is it possible to pass program options in boost without giving argument name like `program.exe var1` instead of `program.exe --arg1 var1`. However I know how to handle this without boost lib with obtaining just `argv[1]`.

There are two cases: one, when I have to specify **all args** with their argNames and two, when I have only **one argument** - `fileName` and now I know how to handle the first one but the problem is second one - how to handle it having all together via in boost lib? Or in simple - is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html) has just such an example:

> The "input-file" option specifies the list of files to process. That's okay for a start, but, of course, writing something like:
>
> ```
> compiler --input-file=a.cpp
> ```
>
> is a little non-standard, compared with
>
> ```
> compiler a.cpp
> ```
>
> We'll address this in a moment.
>
> The command line tokens which have no option name, as above, are called "positional options" by this library. They can be handled too. With a little help from the user, the library can decide that "a.cpp" really means the same as "--input-file=a.cpp". Here's the additional code we need:
>
> ```
> po::positional_options_description p;
> p.add("input-file", -1);
>
> po::variables_map vm;
> po::store(po::command_line_parser(ac, av).
>           options(desc).positional(p).run(), vm);
> po::notify(vm);
> ```
>
> The first two lines say that all positional options should be translated into "input-file" options. Also note that we use the command_line_parser class to parse the command line, not the parse_command_line function. The latter is a convenient wrapper for simple cases, but now we need to pass additional information.

Comment: So if I only want the `input-file` to be the second positional options I need to change -1 to 1 ?

Comment: Nope it's not what I've wanted to do. I need to code two cases: one, when I have to specify all args; two, when I have only one argument - fileName and now I know how to handle the first one but the problem is second one - how to handle it in boost having all together.